# A method to get an AJAX spellchecker in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, spell-checking

So I'm trying to implement a spellchecker in my system, to basically spellcheck certain textboxes in ASP.net. This has proven to be an incredibly difficult task, because no solution exists really, except for users to just use Firefox or some other browser with spellchecking capabilities.

There is the Microsoft Word library option, which is a terrible terrible idea, as it never works properly, requires permission editing, installation of Microsoft Office, and integration with matching versions--meaning you can never move it to another server and expect it to work without a lot of time being spent on compatibility and permissions.

There is this idea, which seems interesting: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/NHunSpell-with-jQuery.aspx

NHunspell ASP.net with jQuery, however, considering their very own example code doesn't even work with .NET 4.0, this seems to be a terrible idea too.

Other options, require developers to pay money to purchase a spellchecker. And I'd rather not do that.

Has anyone found an easy way to put spellcheck on textboxes with just some simple ASP.NET and javascript, without so many libraries/installations.

Comment: One thing that's going to be pretty difficult is to re-style misspelled words as they sit there in simple text inputs or textareas.

Comment: The spell check is difficult, modern browser handle it, in the core of them why not let them ?

Comment: I know right, but I have a problem because some of my users are insistent on using IE. I tell them to get firefox, they blatantly refuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way to do this is to build your own spellchecker using AJAX, jQuery, and perhaps a big dictionary file.